# Three-way optional argument in xparse

Tags: macros, xparse

I am trying to programme a command in x parse that has one optional argument, but which can behave in three ways in the following situations: a) no argument specified, b) optional argument specifies a specific value (p), c) optional argument specifies a different value (q).

The commands would look as follows:

> \command
>
> \command[p]
>
> \command[q]

and would give the result

> command
>
> command preface
>
> command q

I have tried to use the star and token arguments instead of the standard optional argument but the documentation is very sparse for the package and I cannot work out, even from looking at examples on this site, how I might achieve the above.

My attempt was as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \command { tp } {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    command}%
    {{\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {command preface}%
    {command #1}%
    }}}

\begin{document}

\command
\command[p]
\command[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: –1: Questions only asking “do it for me” or the like are not really welcome here. Please add a MWE showing your own efforts and I’ll be happy to take my downvote back ;-)

Comment: `xparse` is meant to grab arguments: further processing of the content is left to 'other code'. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tobi: I thought I might get that response, but I genuinely tried and my efforts were so far from working that I didn't see much point in posting them. Truth is, I didn't really know where to start with the problem. I would have been happy with a response like "here is a site that explains xparse in more detail than the documentation" rather than an actual solution, as I could not find such a resource.

Comment: @DavidRowthorn: Hm … showing some code even if it don’t work will help. I don’t like questions that have the “just do it for me” attitude – and your’s looks that way ;-) But as you can see in the fact that I provided an answer I’m not that upset ;-) and I redeem my downvote. (ps. Note that you need an `@` in front of a name to get the user notified …)

Comment: @Tobi This is my attempt: 

    \NewDocumentCommand \command { tp } {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{command}{{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{command preface}{command #1}}}}

Which as you can see is a mess.

Comment: Furthermore, as egreg says, you interface seems a little strange maybe you can add some information what your trying to implement this way and make the question a little more concrete. Plus: You may add a concrete (new) question about what you don’t understand in the `xparse` manual …

Comment: @DavidRowthorn: Pleas ad this to your question instead of a comment. (I can’t change my vote, as long as the question isn’t edited)

Comment: Since your interface doens’t make sense to me I can hardly tell how to improve your attempt, but see what I added to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need `xparse` in that case. You can do a case switch with the [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

% with xstring
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1][-no-value-]{%
   command does
   \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
      {-no-value-}{no value}%
      {p}{preface}%
   }[#1 value]
   stuff
}

% a more clever version (see comments) with xparse
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myothercmd}{ o }{%
   command does
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{no value}{%
      \IfStrEq{#1}{p}{preface}{#1}%
   }
   stuff
}

\begin{document}
\mycmd

\mycmd[p]

\mycmd[q]

\mycmd[-no-value-] is a 'wrong' argument and confuses the code.
So it should be something where you are sure that it won't be the
argument of \verb+\mycmd+

\bigskip
\myothercmd

\myothercmd[p]

\myothercmd[q]

\mycmd[-NoValue-] \texttt{xparse} know how to handle this.
\end{document}
```

---

Trying to correct your attempt gives

```
\NewDocumentCommand \yourcmd { t{+} o } {%
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{command preface}{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
         command%
      }{%
         command #2%
      }%
   }%
}
```

As you can see the `p` argument take an argument specifying the `<token>` that should be tested this toke cant be a letter, e.g. `p`, because `\yourcmdp` will be another command in TeX’s eyes and *not* `\yourcmd` followed by token `p`. The corrected version can be used as

```
\yourcmd
\yourcmd+
\yourcmd[q]
\yourcmd+[q]
```

giving

> command
>   command preface
>   command q
>   command preface

Comment: Note that `xparse`'s `-NoValue-` is not returned if you do `\mycmd[-NoValue-]`, _i.e_ (without significant effort) you can't 'confuse' the code with the 'wrong' optional argument.

Comment: So you mean, that I should prefer the `xparse` way instead my own `-no-value-` approach?

Comment: Depends on the use case: usually you don't need to worry about users entering 'difficult' values, but it is at least worth being aware of.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that my approach is confusable in that way but I wasn’t aware of the fact that `xparse` is more clever. Thanks!

Comment: I was not aware of the xstring package, but it is exactly what I needed. thanks

Answer (score 3):

`xparse` doesn't provide helpers for this situation, so going deeper with comparing strings is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\command}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    <No optional value code>
   }
   {
    \rowthorn_check_argument:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \rowthorn_check_argument:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {p}{ \rowthorn_command:n { Preface } }
   }
   { \rowthorn_command:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rowthorn_command:n #1
 {
  <do something with #1>
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\command

\command[p]

\command[Introduction]

\end{document}
```

I don't think this is a good interface, though.